# Autogen Studio 2 - api_key is not present in llm_config or OPENAI_API_KEY env variable for agent ** primary_assistant

Tags: autogen

Running autogen studio 2, I have my model setup and tested successful - when I run the travel demo I get the following error:

api_key is not present in llm_config or OPENAI_API_KEY env variable for agent ** primary_assistant**. Update your workflow to provide an api_key to use the LLM.

I have tested the model successfully and the agent is pointing to the correct model.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a conda environment and was able to resolve the issue by setting my env variable and deactivating / reactivating my environment. I used the command below to set my API key:

conda env config vars set OPENAI_API_KEY=value

conda deactivate envName
conda activate envName

Hope this helps!

Comment: conda deactivate envName conda activate envName cast error

Answer (score 1):

For Python Venv:

Deactivate

1. source pyautogen/bin/activate
2. cmd+shift+p Select Interpreter

ensure correct interpreter is selected (use the virtual environment one)

3. export OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-
4. autogenstudio ui --port 8081

Ensure all previous windows are closed.